# Do attacks that give the Grappled condition work against creatures more than 1 size larger?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple, creature-size

Many creatures, such as the Giant Frog, have attacks that grapple on a hit:

> **Bite**. *Melee Weapon Attack:* [...] *Hit:* (1d6 + 1) piercing damage. The target is grappled (escape DC 11).

Does this grapple work against a creature Huge or larger? Usual Grapples don't work if the target is more than one size larger than the grappler.

> The target of your grapple must be no more than one size larger than you and must be within your reach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Don't confuse the *Grappled* condition with the "grappling" attack option.

When you want to grab a creature and hold on to them, the "grappling" attack option is how you accomplish that. The rules for doing this include a size limit on the target. If you succeed, you apply the *grappled* condition to the target.

But the size limit is a function of the grappling attack, not a rule that applies generally to the *grappled* condition. A condition is what it is, as defined in the rules appendix A (PHB p.290).

Spells, feats, magic items, or monster special actions may provide other ways to inflict the *grappled* condition without using the "grapple attack" rules, and therefore have no inherent size limits; the spell, feat, item, or action will specify what limits, if any, apply to it.

So yes, in theory, a giant frog could grapple an ancient dragon and stop it in its tracks. As a DM, you should feel free to overrule this if you feel it's absurd, but it's technically what the rules say.

Comment: @BrunoSouza the Giant Frog only has a size limit on its Swallow ability, not on its Bite.

Answer (score 9):

## They Work as usual

The rules don't specify if the grapple is independent of size, but as the grappling rules for monsters say:

> Many monsters have special attacks that allow them to quickly grapple prey. When a monster hits with such an attack, it doesn't need to make an additional ability check to determine whether the grapple succeeds, unless the attack says otherwise.
>
> A creature grappled by the monster can use its action to try to escape. To do so, it must succeed on a Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check against the escape DC in the monster's stat block. If no escape DC is given, assume the DC is 10 + the monster's Strength (Athletics) modifier.

Since there's nothing specific mentioned on the situation, I assume general grappling rules apply. So treat it as a normal grapple but without the need of a additional ability test.

Note that some monsters specify the size the grapple works on, usually when it's different from the general rule.

Comment: Your last paragraph seems important: If there are clarifications in some places where the intent is to have different grappling mechanics than in the general case, this is a strong hint that general rules are intended to be used where no comment is made.

Answer (score 8):

### Yes, unless the description says otherwise

The grapple ability of many monsters do not necessarily work the same way as a PC grappling. Although the resulting grappled *condition* is identical, the process by which the creature gets grappled just follows the description as given. There is no general rule that says otherwise.

Note that the Giant Frog's "swallow" ability specifically targets a creature it is grappling but *only* if that creature is Small or smaller. So if size matters (so to speak), then it will say so.

Comment: By your answer a medium creature could grapple a gargantuan creature in place. I believe if no size is mentioned, you should use the general size rule.

Comment: @BrunoSouza: I do not believe there IS a "general size rule", which is the source of the confusion perhaps. There is a grappling rule for player characters allowing them to grapple with a special attack (and which mentions size), and there are some special attacks possessed by monsters that allow them to grapple creatures (which may or may not mention size). Both end with a creature grappled, but these are two independent sets of rules.

Comment: But there's no **grappling rule for PCs**, there's just **grappling rules** under **Combat rules**. If you get what i mean.

Comment: I picture a Halfling grappling a Tarrasque...

Comment: @BrunoSouza The rules in the PHB are rules for players, generally speaking, and they don't do anything except what they say. The rules for making a **grapple attack** put a limit on how large the target can be. That attack results in the **grappled condition**, which does not have any rules about how large the target can be.  Monsters (or PCs with spells, feats, or magic items) may have other ways to inflict the **grappled condition** that do not use the "grapple attack" rules and therefore have no size limits except what those specific ways say (such as in the case of the giant frog).

Comment: @DarthPseudonym i don't think the PHB rules are for players, they are general rules that apply to any character in the game. For example, a creature that doesn't have a grapple, sneak, or similar action on its stat block could still try to sneak and grapple using the PHB rules. But you do have a point on the size limiter being on the **grapple attack** and not on the **grappled condition**.